# Return report in html format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports, reportviewer

I wrote a Crystal Report in Visual Studio. The controller uses a SQL query to find a blacklisted truck and return it in PDF format. Now I want to return it as an HTML object to make the report clickable. How can I do this?

```
var c = db.Database.SqlQuery<Models.Reports.blacklisted_truck>(BlacklistedtruckQuery,parameters).ToList();
blacklistedtruck rpt = new blacklistedtruck();

rpt.Load();
rpt.SetDataSource(c);
Stream s = rpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
return File(s, "application/pdf","blacklisted.pdf");
```

Comment: Not sure what is a requirement and your question is not clear....Before generating PDF file you can render to HTML instead and then allow to export to PDF file. Or you can do both render your data to HTML and have separate function which will Generate PDF file and call accordingly.

Comment: I just want to view my crystal report in Viewer,so how to do this,

Comment: hello pratyush, I just want render html,how to do this in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Stream s = rpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.HTML40);
return File(s, "text/html","blacklisted.html");
```